# How to work with multilevel data using Python Pandas?

Tags: python, pandas

I've been trying to get some data which is multilevel data.

My initial data looks like this:

[image]

Using python script I am getting this data.

```
df = pd.read_csv('(path)', header = [0, 1]);
```

Data after reading:

```
Name    Unnamed: 1_level_0  Address Unnamed: 3_level_0  Other Address Details Unnamed: 5_level_0

First Name  Surname            State    City                         Pincode    Landmark

Gaurav       Tiwari         Maharashtra Pune                          411001    Lane-C
Pooja        Mishal         Maharashtra Sawantwadi                    416510    Saliwada
```

[image: Initial Data]

As you see, there are columns that go by the names 'Unnamed: 1_level_0', ... So I renamed the columns with ''.

```
for i, columns_old in enumerate(df.columns.levels):
    columns_new = np.where(columns_old.str.contains('Unnamed'), '', columns_old)
    df.rename(columns = dict(zip(columns_old, columns_new)), level = i, inplace = True)
```

Data after replacing 'Unnamed' columns:

```
Name                          Address                              Other Address Details

First Name  Surname            State    City                         Pincode    Landmark

Gaurav       Tiwari         Maharashtra Pune                          411001    Lane-C
Pooja        Mishal         Maharashtra Sawantwadi                    416510    Saliwada
```

I somehow feel that this is bit ameteurish to address this multilevel data this way.

1. If I want to retrieve column data like Surname/First Name, then I have to write:

   ```
   df['']['Surname']      // don't want to do [''].

   df['']['First Name']      // don't want to do [''].
   ```

   I want to address these columns of like:

   ```
    df['Name']['First Name']

    df['Name']['Surname']
   ```
2. Also the data is getting populated with blank columns('') if I approach my data this way which is not good in long run. Is there a more better way to write this data in python while retaining the same schema as in initial data(look first image i.e Excel data)?

Comment: can you provide your data as text and not an image? see [mcve] and [ask]

Comment: @Umar.H: I've made changes to the question as per your convenience. I hope this gives better interpretation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`MultiIndex.to_frame`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.MultiIndex.to_frame.html) for new `DataFrame` from columns names, so possible replace `Unnamed` to missing values in [`Series.mask`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.mask.html) and forward filling missing values, last create `MultiIndex` by [`MultiIndex.from_frame`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.MultiIndex.from_frame.html):

```
df = pd.read_csv('(path)', header = [0, 1])

print (df.columns)
MultiIndex([(                 'Name', 'First Name'),
            (    'Unnamed:1_level_0',    'Surname'),
            (              'Address',      'State'),
            (   'Unnamed: 3_level_0',       'City'),
            ('Other Address Details',    'Pincode'),
            (   'Unnamed: 5_level_0',   'Landmark')],
           )

df1 = df.columns.to_frame()
df1.columns = ['lvl1','lv2']
df1['lvl1'] = df1['lvl1'].mask(df1['lvl1'].str.contains('Unnamed')).ffill()

df.columns = pd.MultiIndex.from_frame(df1)
print (df.columns)
MultiIndex([(                 'Name', 'First Name'),
            (                 'Name',    'Surname'),
            (              'Address',      'State'),
            (              'Address',       'City'),
            ('Other Address Details',    'Pincode'),
            ('Other Address Details',   'Landmark')],
           names=['lvl1', 'lv2'])
```

Comment: Also sorry for late reply.

Comment: Ignore my previous comment, your approach works great.

Answer (score 1):

Try using a multiindex https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/advanced.html

```
tuples = [('bar', 'one'),
          ('bar', 'two'),
          ('baz', 'one'),
          ('baz', 'two'),
          ('foo', 'one'),
          ('foo', 'two'),
          ('qux', 'one'),
          ('qux', 'two')]
index = pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples(tuples, names=["first", "second"])
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(3, 8), index=["A", "B", "C"], columns=index)
df
Out[19]: 
first        bar                 baz                 foo                 qux          
second       one       two       one       two       one       two       one       two
A       0.895717  0.805244 -1.206412  2.565646  1.431256  1.340309 -1.170299 -0.226169
B       0.410835  0.813850  0.132003 -0.827317 -0.076467 -1.187678  1.130127 -1.436737
C      -1.413681  1.607920  1.024180  0.569605  0.875906 -2.211372  0.974466 -2.006747
```

Then access:

```
df["bar", "one"]
Out[26]: 
A    0.895717
B    0.410835
C   -1.413681
Name: (bar, one), dtype: float64
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of renaming the first level (0) of your columns index, you could simply drop it and keep the second one:

```py
df = pd.read_csv('(path)', header = [0, 1])
df = df.droplevel(0, axis=1)

print(df)
# Outputs
First Name    Surname        State         City          Pincode    Landmark
Gaurav        Tiwari         Maharashtra   Pune          411001     Lane-C
Pooja         Mishal         Maharashtra   Sawantwadi    416510     Saliwada
```

Comment: What happens if there are repeated column names in level 1?

Comment: That the not an issue here, but in that case, I suppose it would throw an error, so to avoid that, you would have to rename columns on level 1 before dropping level 0.